# Обработка нажатий клавиш несколькими JComponent

Tags: java, swing

Имеется JFrame в котором расположены JList и JTextField.
Проблема заключается в том что при вводе текста в JTextField JList теряет фокус и в нем нельзя выбирать элементы клавишами-стрелками. Как одновременно принимать события нажатия стрелок в JList и продолжать редактировать текст в JTextField?

Answer (score 1):

События, происходящие в масштабе программы, можно прослушивать следующим образом: getToolkit().addAWTEventListener;
Идея в следующем: выцеплять из общей очереди сообщений нажатия стрелок и отправлять их в компонент методом processEvent(event);
Вот что я добавил в конструктор MyJList:

```
getToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        final int KEY_DOWN=40;
        final int KEY_UP=38;
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            int keyCode=((KeyEvent)event).getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KEY_DOWN|keyCode == KEY_UP) MyJList.this.processEvent(event);
        }
    },AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```